# Derivation of the third moment of Poisson distribution using Stein-Chen identity

Tags: probability

> (a) Use LOTUS to show that for $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ and any function g, $E(Xg(X)) = λE(g(X + 1))$.
>   This is called the Stein-Chen identity for the Poisson.
>
> (b) Find the third moment $E(X^3)$ for $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ by using the identity from (a) and a
>   bit of algebra to reduce the calculation to the fact that $X$ has mean $\lambda$ and variance $\lambda$.

Only part b) is concerned. My solution

Let $g(X) = X^2$, then

\begin{align}
E(X^3) &= \lambda E(g(X+1)) \\
&= \lambda E((X+1)^2) \\
&= \lambda (E(X^2) + 2E(X) + 1) \\
&= \lambda (\lambda+\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 1)\\
&= \lambda^3 + 3\lambda^2 + \lambda
\end{align}

However, from litarature I know that the third moment should be $\lambda$. What went wrong?

Comment: The third *central* moment is $E[(X-\lambda)^3]=\lambda$. The third moment is given by your formula, which is correct.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the same thing. I'm just learning about that stuff. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Dominik To help keep down the number of unanswered questions, could you please paste your correct solution down as an answer, and accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sasha I did so, but I'll have to wait for 2 days to be able to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to keep the number of unanswered questions low.

Let $g(X) = X^2$, then

\begin{align}
E(X^3) &= \lambda E(g(X+1)) \\
&= \lambda E((X+1)^2) \\
&= \lambda (E(X^2) + 2E(X) + 1) \\
&= \lambda (\lambda+\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 1)\\
&= \lambda^3 + 3\lambda^2 + \lambda
\end{align}