# Kurtosis poisson

Tags: statistics, moment-problem

I am trying to find the kurtosis of the Poisson - 
I found

E(X <sup>4</sup>)) = λ<sup>4</sup> + 6λ<sup>3</sup> + 7λ<sup>2</sup> + λ`

The 4<sup>th</sup> central moment I calculated with the binomial expansion:

E(X <sup>4</sup>)) - 4 E(X <sup>3</sup>)) E(X) + 6E(X <sup>2</sup>)) E(X)<sup>2</sup> - 4E(X)E(X)<sup>3</sup> + E(X)<sup>4</sup>

= λ<sup>4</sup> + 6λ<sup>3</sup> + 7λ<sup>2</sup> + λ - 4λ(λ<sup>3</sup> + 3λ<sup>2</sup> + λ) + 6λ<sup>2</sup>(λ<sup>2</sup> + λ) - 4λ<sup>4</sup> + λ<sup>4</sup>

However, I got 4λ<sup>2</sup>/λ<sup>2</sup> when dividing it with sigma<sup>4</sup> - according to a solution I got I should be 1/λ.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of $\mathsf E[X^3]$ is not correct. Another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1075748/350875) derives it as

$$\mathsf E[X^3]=\lambda^3 + \color{red}3\lambda^2 + \lambda$$

Comment: Didn't copy it correctly - I calculated it with your calculation and got the abovementioned result.

Comment: Your last calculations is also wrong. It is $3\lambda^2 + \lambda$. Then when you divide it by $\lambda^2$ it becomes $3+\lambda^{-1}$, and if you subtract $3$ it gives you the excess Kurtosis, which is $\lambda^{-1}$.